# How do I center this number inside the circle? - CSS

Tags: html, css

You can see the implementation [here](http://jsfiddle.net/VScFS/)

I would like the numbers in the top left of each box, to be centered in the middle of the circles.

Help!

Comment: your process is all wrong, you need step 4: ??? and only then 5: profit

Comment: Nice to see border-radius used for circles like that. Won't work in IE of course, though if you care about IE you may want to try the IE-hack at http://css3pie.com to rectify that.

Comment: @Spudley Dude...this is exactly what I been looking for. Thnx.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Set `line-height` to the height of the box and use `text-align: center;`

So you would get, for example :

```
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    line-height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
}
```